# (Tensor) Product of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$
Suppose that $T: G \rightarrow \GL(U)$ and $ S: G \rightarrow \GL(V)$ are two finite dimensional irreducible representations of some group $G$ .

I consider the  tensor product representation $ T^*S : G \rightarrow \GL( U^* \otimes V)$ ,

where $T^*$ is the dual representation of $T$.

I know that $T^*S $ can be written as a finite sum of irreducible representations $ T^*S = \displaystyle \sum_{k} m_k T_k$.

I want to show that if for some $k$ , $T_k$ is the trivial representation, then $m_k \le 1$.

Can anyone give me a hint to get started please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
Hint: $U^*\otimes V\cong \Hom(U,V)$ with the usual action of $G$ on $\Hom(U,V)$. The trivial submodules here are exactly the subspaces of $\Hom_G(U,V)$. What does Schur's Lemma say about this? (I'm assuming you are working over a suitable algebraically closed field).

Comment: Oh yes, I am working over $\mathbb{C}$. I'm not sure I entirely follow though... The version of Schur's lemma which I'm familiar with is that in Vinberg's which says that "Every endomorphism of an irreducible complex representation $T$ is scalar" Could you maybe elaborate a bit? Thanks :)

Comment: So what does that say about the dimension of $Hom_G(U,V)$? Remember that $U$ and $V$ are irreducible.

Comment: By Schur's lemma, it's 1 if $U \cong V$ and 0 otherwise right? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I got one more question if I may... Why does it necessarily have to contain the trivial representation if $~~ U \cong V$?